# Laravel hasManyThrough same model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Post model, which has a relation to model Comment, and Comment is polymorphic because a comment can be associate with a post, or with another comment.

The issue is I have no idea how to grab the Comments which are associated with other Comment using an eager load.

Here is a piece of code to show you what I am doing right now

```
$postsData = Post::whereIn('user_id', $followsArray)->with('postImages')->with('user')->with('comments')->latest()->get();
```

So basically I want to do is [...]->with('comments')->with('comments'), to get the comments of the comments.

That doesn't work because the Post model does not have a relation to those comments, only the commentable comments do. I tried to give the Post model a hasManyThrough relation to those comments, but laravel blows up because it does not use alises for the tables, and since the table is the same - 'comments' this doesn't work.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, Comment::class, 'id', 'commentable_id');
```

I tried to make my own DB query in the Post model like so

```
return DB::table('comments as c1')->get();
```

just to test if I can pull stuff from the DB on my own, but I get an error `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.`

... What I can do is to fetch the Posts, get their Ids and using them fetch the comments and their comments with a separate collection, but then I won't be able to connect each post to its comments since they are separate collections. At least I don't know how to merge the collections properly. Here is what I have done in this regard so far:

```
    $postsData = Post::whereIn('user_id', $followsArray)->with('postImages')->with('user')->latest()->get();
    $postsIds = $postsData->pluck('id');
    $commentsData = Comment::whereIn('commentable_id', $postsIds)->where('commentable_type','App\Post')->with('comments')->get();
```

Sooo I need assistance with this, bottom line what I need to do is get the posts, with the comments associated to them, and the comments associated to those comments in the same collection.

I tried to look in the docs, but all I found was merging functions which don't actually associate the comments, but instead just push them to the end of the array of posts.

Looking for suggestions sorry if the question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Is there only one level deeper of comments? Ie) can there be posts->with('comments.comments.comments')?

Comment: You should share the schema you have defined in your migrations for the relevant tables, and the relationships you have defined in your models as well.

Comment: Only one deep so far. A comment to a Comment, I don't plan on having them two or more levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to use nested eager loading, as mentioned in the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
At Nested Eager loading we can do with('comments.comments') and this will load the comments of the comments just as intended.

Hopefully, someone finds this useful, I know I did.